# How do i put a logo on the left but not all the way left just in the middle?

Tags: html, css

i tried using this code
`<div id="logo" style="background-image:`
`url('http://comprogroup2ict2b.rf.gd/logo.png');`
`width: 100px; height: 50px; background-size: contain;`
`background-repeat:no-repeat; float: left">`
`</div>`
but i cant seem to make it semi center left

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

you should try some margining like margin-top:50%

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).